# SQL Error [S1009]: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

Me sale este error en Dbeaver de repente. Alguna vez me pasó en el pasado y borrando la aplicación al igual que Xampp me funcionó, pero ahora intenté eso y nada, no sé cómo cambiarlo o solucionarlo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la pregunta tiene más de 3 meses en este momento veo que nadie a respondido, por lo que comparto mi caso:

Tuve el mismo tema, en mi caso tengo DBeaver 23.0.3 Estuve revisando y encontré que tenía el **Auto-commit** en True, lo quité y pude correr el query sin problema.

Clic derecho sobre el **nombre de la base** >**connection settings** > **initialization** y **Auto-commit** en false.[image: DBeaver 23.0.3]